# patroni returning 503 on 8008 check in haproxy

Tags: haproxy, patroni

I'm doing a test of a patroni cluster before implementing in production. I have almost identical configs on my two patroni/postgresql servers, save for IP addresses. Haproxy shows that my second box is always down, and returns the following:

```
Dec 31 09:05:45 db-haproxy haproxy[945]: [WARNING] 364/090545 (945) : Server postgres/postgresql_10.150.33.12_5432 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 503, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>503<3E>", check duration: 2ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

Both systems are running in LXC containers on a Proxmox box

Advice is welcome